# I'm trying to highlight cells that don't contain specific text from a list in Excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight cells that **DO NOT** contain specific terms. I have seen other posts that will highlight the listed terms, but not one that will highlight the cells that do not contain the terms.

In Sheet1, Column A, I have a long list of Job Titles.

| Job Title |
| --- |
| Marketing Manager |
| Director of Planning |
| Cat Wrangler |
| Mktg Mgr |
| Asphalt Marketer |

In Sheet2, Column B, I have a list of terms that I want to search for:

| Terms |
| --- |
| Marketing |
| Mktg |
| Marketer |

I would like to use Conditional Formatting in Sheet1, Column A to highlight the job titles that **DO NOT** appear in Sheet 2, Column B

So for the above list, the following cells would be highlighted in Sheet1, Column A:

| Job Title |
| --- |
| Director of Planning |
| Cat Wrangler |

These words would not be highlighted:

| Job Title |
| --- |
| Marketing Manager |
| Mktg Mgr |
| Asphalt Marketer |

Comment: Conditional Formatting, use `COUNTIF()`. What have you tried?

Comment: Select the `Column A` in `Sheet 1` & use this formula in conditional formatting rule use a formula to determine which cells to format `=NOT(ISNUMBER(--CONCAT(IFERROR(SEARCH(" "&'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$4&" "," "&'Sheet1'!A2&" "),""))))`

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH($E$2:$E$4,$A2),""))=0
```

In case of `Sheet2` use-

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4,$A2),""))=0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using new BETA-functionality for exact matching:

[image]

Formula applied to `A1:A5`:

```
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT($A1," ")=C$1:C$3))=0
```

Or, if not available, on can follow the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72253955/9758194) perfectly fine with concatenated spaces in lookup-value and lookup-range.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above, if you are using **O365**, then please ***try***,

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]

• Formula used in Conditional Formatting

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(--CONCAT(IFERROR(SEARCH(" "&$C$2:$C$4&" "," "&A2&" "),""))))
```

---

And If your search value is in `Sheet2` then,

```
 =NOT(ISNUMBER(--CONCAT(IFERROR(SEARCH(" "&'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$4&" "," "&'Sheet1'!A2&" "),""))))
```

---

Or, If you don't have access to **O365** then try using with `LOOKUP()` Function with `SEARCH()` & `ISNA()` Function, `LOOKUP()` certainly helpful in such scenarios.

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]

• Formula used in Conditional Formatting

```
=ISNA(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,A2)))
```

---

With `Sheet2` use

```
=ISNA(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH('Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$4,'Sheet1'!A2)))
```

---